# Finite State Automaton Language

Tags: automata, finite-automata

We're given these two finite state machines where the alphabet consists of ${a, b, c}$. The question is to determine the language for the following two machines. I tried following the machines to find the language, but the languages I derived are quite verbose.

## FSA #1

[image]

This FSA accepts words with at least one a followed by zero or more b's or words with at least one a followed by zero or more b's followed by at least one c.

## FSA #2

[image]

This  FSA accepts words with at least one a followed by at least one b or words with at least one a followed by at least one b followed by one c.

I tried converting these FSAs to regular expressions and found that my solutions hold up, but I'm wondering if there is a more concise way to explain the language of each FSA. My language explanations seem quite verbose, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question asks us to grade your answers. This is your TA's job rather than the goal of this site.

Answer (score 1):

Finite state automatons recognize regular languages. The advantage of regular languages is that it is usually trivial to express them formally.

## FSA #1

$$L(M_1) = \left\{ a^kb^lc^m | k > 0, l \geq 0, m \in \{ 0, 1 \} \right\}$$

## FSA #2

$$L(M_2) = \left\{ a^kb^lc^m | k > 0, l > 0, m \in \{ 0, 1 \} \right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

You could be more precise by stating "This FSA accepts a word if, and only if, ...". You could be more concise by using the word "optional" in the "...".

Comment: This might work better as a comment. Perhaps you could provide one or more full solutions for one of the two problems. Also, we usually don't answer such questions, which require grading somebody's work.

Comment: I sensed as much, whence I avoided giving full answers. And yes, a comment would've been enough.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expressions corresponding to your descriptions are as follows.

---

**FSA #1**

$$a^{*+1} b^* + a^{*+1} b^* c$$

... which can be simplified to

$$a^{*+1} b^* (\epsilon + c)$$

... or, in John Conway's notation

$$a^{*+1} b^* c^{\le 1}$$

We can describe this as

- one or more $a$s, followed by ...
- any number of $b$s, followed by ...
- a possible $c$.

---

**FSA #2**

$$a^{*+1} b^{*+1} + a^{*+1} b^{*+1} c$$

... which can be simplified to

$$a^{*+1} b^{*+1} (\epsilon + c)$$

... or, in John Conway's notation

$$a^{*+1} b^{*+1} c^{\le 1}$$

We can describe this as

- one or more $a$s, followed by ...
- one or more $b$s, followed by ...
- a possible $c$.

---

You can see that these correspond to [@still_learning's prescriptions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/70814/16617).